# Why does podman generate container systemd files for a pod?

Tags: podman

I hope this is a simple question. When creating a Podman pod with one or more containers,
the Podman generate command will create a systemd file for the pod, but also systemd files for the containers, which it will depend on.

Is this really needed, why?
Wouldn't one file for the pod, that calls 'podman pod start', and 'podman pod stop' be enough?
Would I miss something important if I were to use that approach?

Asking because I'm trying to set up a system with a deploy pipeline, where the container count/names isn't really known in advance. So being able to do 'podman pod stop', 'podman pod rm', and then rebuilding the new version, while just reusing the same pod systemd file, would be a lot easier than having to clean up and recreate container systemd files :)

Thank you!

Comment: "Wouldn't one file for the pod, that calls 'podman pod start', and 'podman pod stop' be enough?" What if the pod didn't already exist? The generated files are designed so that you can place them on a system and `systemctl start` things and it will bring up all the necessary infrastructure.

Comment: That's only the case if you use --new isn't it?

Comment: I'm actually not sure -- I don't regularly use this particular feature of podman, so it's possible my previous comment was inaccurate.